# NUMBER datatype in oracle sql database rounding values inserted from java

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am inserting data from java into the oracle database.

```
ps1.setDouble(4, Double.parseDouble(record.get(3)));
```

record.get(3) is a string containing a -250.8. Even if I do

```
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(record.get(3)));
```

I get -250.8

The code runs fine, but what I see in the oracle database is -251. The data type in Oracle is `Number(38,0)` which accepts decimal numbers.

How can I have the decimal value show in oracle?

I also tried Float in Java instead of Double with no success

Comment: What is the full data type?  A `number` has a precision and a scale.  If the scale is 0, the column only accepts integers which would account for the rounding

Comment: it says Number(38,0) not sure what that means

Comment: `NUMBER(38,0)` means 38 digits, with 0 of them fractional, i.e. it can store only whole numbers (integers). The database is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing. If you want floating point numbers, use `NUMBER` without any parentheses and digits. Better yet, use `BINARY_DOUBLE` (added in 11g).

Comment: Thank you . Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Oracle data type of `NUMBER(38,0)` means that the column has a precision of 38 and a scale of 0.  That means that the column can store a value with up to 38 digits but 0 digits after the decimal place.  That is, it only allows integers.  If you try to insert a non-integer value, that value has to be rounded to the nearest integer as part of the `INSERT` operation.

If you want to allow the column to have value with, say, 5 decimal places, you would want to define it as `NUMBER(38,5)`.

Comment: Or `NUMBER` for no fixed scale, or `BINARY_DOUBLE` (added in 11g) for exact data type match with Java `double`.